# How post message on facebook without open any dialog?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to post messages on facebook without open dialog using native Facebook android app.
I am using facebook sdk 3.5.2.
I have successfully post messages on wall.

I am facing some problems.

1) if I logout from native Facebook app. Then it post messages to previous user's Facebook wall & it not ask for authentication.

2)If user login with different account in Facebook native app, it still post messages to
previous account( which login first time through app). Not ask for authentication.

**Code:-**

```
 Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        new messagePostAsyn().execute(session);

                    }
                }
              });
```

**Method:**

```
 private void postStatus(final Session session, String message) {


    Bundle _postParameter = new Bundle();
    _postParameter.putString("name", message);

    _postParameter.putByteArray("picture", bytes);
    _postParameter.putString("caption", "To help....");
    _postParameter.putString("description", "Testing...");
    Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", _postParameter,
            HttpMethod.POST, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("response......" + response);

                }
            });



    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);


}
```

This method used in messagePostAsyn() class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", message);

    // Uses the Facebook Graph API
    try {
        facebook.request("/me/feed", params, "POST");
        this.finish();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why post messages after logout from native app?In this we need to clear tokens after posting messages.

Comment: Is there any way to know if user is logout from native facebook app then my app ask for login otherwise not ask from login?

Comment: Please do not use the Facebook class anymore, that whole class has been deprecated and will not be supported. There's no way to know if the user has logged out from the native Facebook app.